# Android MediaPlayer seekTo method doesn't work on JellyBean devices but works fine on Gingebread, Froyo

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm having some trouble with the MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec) method.  Basically I'm using a SeekBar to track the progress of the stream (.mp3 file being streamed).  I allow the user to move the seek bar to seek to a different part of the stream. When they seek I use the onStopTrackingTouch() in the OnSeekBarChangeListener to track exactly where they seeked to.  I then pass this millisecond value to my streaming service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, StreamingService.class);
intent.setAction(StreamingService.SERVICE_SEEK_TO);
intent.putExtra(StreamingService.EXTRA_SEEK_TO, seekBar.getProgress());
mContext.startService(intent);
```

The Streaming Service handles this intent and attempts to call mediaPlayer.seekTo().  This works fine on my Froyo and Gingerbread devices, but it does not work on my JellyBean device.  For example, if I seek to 40,000 msec, my JellyBean device jumps back to 10,000 msec.  Whereas on Gingerbread or Froyo the seek actually works and plays starting from 40,000 msec.  Is there anything wrong with MediaPlayer in JellyBean?

Comment: Hmmm, no answer?  Anyone have any clue?  I know NPR has it working somehow.

Comment: It's working in NPR because they are using a different stream type: ShoutCast

Answer (score 0):

As tokudu mentions in his comment; the stream type is very important.  It worked for NPR because they were using ShoutCast.